# Performed .gitignore command and lost my visual studio code virtual environment

Tags: python, git, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I'm currently running on windows subsystem for linux (wsl2) and was working in a virtual environment `venv`.

Unfortunately, (for some reason), I had thousands of changes showing in source control [5000+ changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VWon.png) and following advice [from here](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/vs-code-has-5000-files-that-need-to-be-commit/250686) I created a new file called .gitignore in my main directory (where all files are) and saved it with the entry "node_modules". I then ran "git init" but this has now deleted my virtual environment -- whenever I try to run `source .env/bin/activate`
all I get is the error message that `bash: .env/bin/activate: No such file or directory`

Also, the colour of my username has changed from green to grey (the below are not my terminal images, but just examples of the change in color):

[What the color of my username used to look like on the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHFz1.png)

[What the color of my username now looks like on the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26Xbj.png)

I imagine this is related to what happened above, but if anyone could please direct me as to how to restore my virtual environment if possible, that'd be amazing (as I now no longer have several packages that were installed) -- I deleted the .gitignore file that was created in my main directory and have done "git init" again, but still facing the same issues as that there's no virtual environment.

Comment: Neither creating a `.gitignore` file nor running `git init` will delete any files. Either you virtualenv is still there, or it was deleted by some other means.

Comment: Make sure you are in the right folder before you do `source .env/bin/activate`. Start by checking if ".env" folder exists or not.

Comment: @ShagunSodhani Hi, my .env folder is still there -- could you possibly elaborate as to where I should run the ```source .env/bin/activate``` command? I tried ```cd .env``` and running it there, but to no avail. Thanks.

Comment: Great so you havent lost anything at all. Can you make sure (just to be safe) that `.env/bin` (folder) and `.env/bin/activate` (file) exist.

Comment: @ShagunSodhani I just checked and ```.env/bin/__pycache__``` exists, but I unfortunately can't find ```.env/bin/activate```

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l .env/bin`? (Don't paste it here, just describe it.)

Comment: @SvenMarnach It gives "total" with an integer value and then a bunch of text "dr..." with an earlier time today and ends with __py__cache__

Comment: Is on eof the file name `activate`? The file names are in the last column.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I ended up just deleting my virtualenv and reinstalling the packages due to other complications -- thanks for helping though :)